# Correlation and analytic function

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table looks like

```
TDate         Name     Value     
20110101     xxx      1.2
20110102     xxx      1.3
...
20110101     yyy      3.4
20110101     yyy      32.1
```

I want to calculate the the correlation of value between each name (say between xxx and yyy). Here is my code:

```
Create table corrDEC as
Select distinct a.name ASymbol,b.name BSymbol, 
corr(a.value,b.value) over (partition by a.name,b.name)  Correlation
From logprofitDEC a, logprofitDEC b
where a.name<>b.name
Order by 1,2,3 desc;
```

Do I have to add

```
where To_date(a.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')=To_date(b.Tdate,'YYYYMMDD')
```

in the where clause please?

Comment: Add a.Tdate to the select statement and get rid of distinct. And add `and a.Tdate=b.Tdate` to the where clause

Comment: May I ask why it is necessary to add a.Tdate=b.Tdate please?